# Why wont git add changes to be committed?

Tags: git

I'm trying to add some changes and commit them using git. Could somebody please tell me why I can't use the normal `git add *` and `commit` those changes? Here are some screen shots showing whats happening.

```
$ git status
```

[image]

```
$ git add *
```

[image]

```
$ git commit ...
```

[image]

Comment: Are you at the root of your repository?

Comment: What's the output of `echo *`..? (This is not a git issue)

Comment: @CiaranWelsh Good practice is to paste the log in text format instead Image here so that other can copy and paste your log in Answer section.

Comment: Ah no, I'm in a subdirectory! Perhaps this is the problem. Output of `echo *` is the files in the subdirectory. @sajib kahn I'll bear this in mind for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `git add -A` cause deleted files exist.

```
$ git add -A      # stage New, Modified and Deleted files

$ git commit -m 'Remove scripts folder and update pycopi'
$ git push origin HEAD
```

**N.B.** `git add .` stage only `new` and `modified` files not `deleted` files.

Comment: For some reason this produced the same problem described in the  question. @R.A.Munna answer however solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, you have deleted files so, you exactly need `git add -A` command. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `$git add -A`. for more you can visit [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html).